# WeMos D1 Mini esptool.FatalError: Timed out waiting for packet header

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

I have a **WeMos D1 Mini**. Here is the board information:

```
Arduino: 1.8.9 (Windows Store 1.8.21.0) (Windows 10), Board: "LOLIN(WEMOS) D1 R2 & mini, 80 MHz, Flash, Legacy (new can return nullptr), All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 4MB (FS:2MB OTA:~1019KB), v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"
```

I am trying to upload the blink program but getting the following error:

```
Executable segment sizes:


IROM   : 228360          - code in flash         (default or ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR) 


IRAM   : 26564   / 32768 - code in IRAM          (ICACHE_RAM_ATTR, ISRs...) 


DATA   : 1236  )         - initialized variables (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 


RODATA : 1520  ) / 81920 - constants             (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 


BSS    : 24896 )         - zeroed variables      (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 


Sketch uses 257680 bytes (24%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
Global variables use 27652 bytes (33%) of dynamic memory, leaving 54268 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
esptool.py v2.8
Serial port COM5
Connecting....
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
Crystal is 26MHz
MAC: 38:2b:78:04:7a:c0
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Configuring flash size...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adiba\OneDrive\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.1/tools/upload.py", line 69, in <module>
    esptool.main(cmdline)
  File "C:/Users/adiba/OneDrive/Documents/ArduinoData/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.6.1/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 2933, in main
    detect_flash_size(esp, args)
  File "C:/Users/adiba/OneDrive/Documents/ArduinoData/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.6.1/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 2241, in detect_flash_size
    flash_id = esp.flash_id()
  File "C:/Users/adiba/OneDrive/Documents/ArduinoData/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.6.1/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 607, in flash_id
    return self.run_spiflash_command(SPIFLASH_RDID, b"", 24)
  File "C:/Users/adiba/OneDrive/Documents/ArduinoData/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.6.1/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 853, in run_spiflash_command
    old_spi_usr = self.read_reg(SPI_USR_REG)
  File "C:/Users/adiba/OneDrive/Documents/ArduinoData/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.6.1/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 490, in read_reg
    val, data = self.command(self.ESP_READ_REG, struct.pack('<I', addr))
  File "C:/Users/adiba/OneDrive/Documents/ArduinoData/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.6.1/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 347, in command
    p = self.read()
  File "C:/Users/adiba/OneDrive/Documents/ArduinoData/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.6.1/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 292, in read
    return next(self._slip_reader)
  File "C:/Users/adiba/OneDrive/Documents/ArduinoData/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.6.1/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 2045, in slip_reader
    raise FatalError("Timed out waiting for packet %s" % waiting_for)
esptool.FatalError: Timed out waiting for packet header
esptool.FatalError: Timed out waiting for packet header

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Is there any solution for this? My friend has tried this board on his computer and it seems to work just fine. Thanks for any support.

Comment: I have the problem repeatedly, with some boards & not others. Have tried the "Ground D3" fix but that has never worked...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I receive the same error, my solution was:

1. remove usb from wemos D1 mini
2. solder wire D3 to GND
3. plug usb
4. upload your Sketch
5. disconnect D3 from GND

Comment: Yeah, thanks for answering it, but after I installed Arduino IDE from the Windows Store, it seemed to work file.

Comment: This fixed my problem, but I don't know why!  Is D3 used for uploading?  According to my schematic, it's just GPIO0.